# User identity loading by itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-identification

I have a user page, where I create users, the fields of login and password is loading by default from the User identity.

Can someone explain to me why is it happening?

Here's the code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginName)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginName, new { @maxlength = "30", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Login" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginName)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword)
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.UserPassword, new { @maxlength = "50", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Senha" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword)
```

Comment: "the fields of login and password is loading by default from the User identity." Can you explain this a bit better... it's really not clear what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that chrome was autofilling my fields, there's a better explanation here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was the autocomplete of my browser.

Sorry for the inconvenience.